# returning variable values in recursion

Tags: python, recursion

I want to return the sum of values of all the left leaves in a tree but it seems that values in my "total" variable are being lost when it returns back to the caller. Can I know a way around this?

```
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def sumOfLeftLeaves(self, root: TreeNode) -> int:
        total = 0
        if root is None:
            return 0
        if root.left:
            sum1 = self.getLeftSum(root.left, total)
        if root.right:
            sum2 = self.getLeftSum(root.right, total)
        return sum1 + sum2

    def getLeftSum(self, cur_node, total):
        if cur_node.left:
            self.getLeftSum(cur_node.left, total)
        if cur_node.left is None and cur_node.right is None:
            total += cur_node.val
        return total
```

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value returned by `self.getLeftSum(cur_node.left, total)`. You should probably add that to the total, no?

Comment: but i want to reach to the left most leaf of a particular branch, so unless its that I don't want add it to the total variable

Comment: It sounds like you want to return left leaf values, but 0 for right leaves, and sum them all.

Answer (score 0):

I see this as a pair of intertwined recursive functions:

```
class Solution:
    def sumOfLeftLeaves(self, node):
        total = 0

        if node:
            if node.left:
                total += self.sumOfLeftLeaf(node.left)

            return total + self.sumOfLeftLeaves(node.right)

        return total

    def sumOfLeftLeaf(self, node):
        total = node.val

        if node.left:
            total += self.sumOfLeftLeaf(node.left)

        return total + self.sumOfLeftLeaves(node.right)
```

One is a general node handler and the other specializes in left hand nodes.

Comment: also known as [_mutual recursion_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) ^^

Answer (score -1):

This answer assumes you wish to sum each `val` that occurs in a `left` branch. The numbers we wish to sum are highlighted below as `(n)` -

```py
#        6
#       / \
#     (5)  8
#     /   / \
#   (3) (4)  9
#   / \     / 
# (1)  7  (2)
```

Using your `TreeNode` class, we build `my_tree` -

```py
my_tree = \
  TreeNode \
    ( 6
    , TreeNode
        ( 5
        , TreeNode(3, TreeNode(1), TreeNode(7))
        , None
        )
    , TreeNode
        ( 8
        , TreeNode(4)
        , TreeNode(9, TreeNode(2), None)
        )
    )
```

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects. We can write `sum_left` as an ordinary function that operates on a `TreeNode` -

```py
def sum_left (t, is_left=False):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return \
      (t.val if is_left else 0) \
      + sum_left(t.left, True)  \
      + sum_left(t.right, False)
```

Which is the less verbose way of saying the same thing below -

```py
def sum_left (t, is_left=False):
  if not t:
    return 0
  elif is_left:
    return t.val + sum_left(t.left, True) + sum_left(t.right, False)
  else:
    return 0 + sum_left(t.left, True) + sum_left(t.right, False)
```

Let's see the computed `sum_left` now -

```py
print(sum_left(my_tree))
# 5 + 3 + 1 + 4 + 2
```

```py
=> 15
```

---

Another option is to use [mutual recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_recursion) -

```py
def sum_left (t):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return t.val + sum_left(t.left) + sum_right(t.right)

def sum_right (t):
  if not t:
    return 0
  else:
    return sum_left(t.left) + sum_right(t.right)
```

Here it makes a difference how you treat the root node. Calling `sum_left` directly on the root will sum the root node as well -

```
print(sum_left(my_tree))
# 6 + 5 + 3 + 1 + 4 + 2
```

```py
=> 21
```

If you want to exclude the root node, you can call `sum_left` on the left node and `sum_right` on the right branch -

```py
print(sum_left(my_tree.left) + sum_right(my_tree.right))
# 5 + 3 + 1 + 4 + 2
```

```py
=> 15
```

Or, counter-intuitive as it may seem, simply call `sum_right` on `my_tree` -

```py
print(sum_right(my_tree))
# 5 + 3 + 1 + 4 + 2
```

```py
=> 15
```